# Counting multiple fields in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table listing People's First Names, their Age, and their favorite color.

I need to create a query in SQL (In access) that counts how many people like Red, and how many people like Yellow.

So far I have written this:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) as "People who like Yellow or Red"  
FROM Table1  
WHERE Table1.[Favorite Color]='Red'  
OR Table1.[Favorite Color]='Yellow';
```

But this returns the TOTAL count of people who like Yellow/Red (In my case, 5)

I have three people who like Yellow, and two who like Red, how can I show those counts independently of each other?

Comment: @I recommend you use the GROUP BY clause of the SELECT statement. On top of my head, it is  SELECT [Favorite Color], COUNT([Favorite Color]) FROM Table1 GROUP BY [Favorite Color]

Answer (score 4):

The generic solution is using the GROUP BY operator.  This will partition your data based on who likes what color and then count up each group separately.

```
SELECT
  Table1.[Favorite Color],
  COUNT(*) as "People who like this color"
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.[Favorite Color];
```

If you only want Red and Yellow in the output, you can add that predicate:

```
SELECT
  Table1.[Favorite Color],
  COUNT(*) as "People who like this color"
FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.[Favorite Color] IN ('Red','Yellow')
GROUP BY Table1.[Favorite Color];
```

Comment: correct me if I am wrong .. but shouldn't we use `having` with a group by?

Comment: `HAVING` would be used if you wanted to limit based on an aggregate, ie `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` would only show favorites that appeared more than once.  `WHERE` is appropriate if you don't care about the aggregate and just want to limit on values of a field.

Comment: "HAVING" is for predicates that depend on an aggregate, such as "HAVING COUNT(*) > 2".

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `CASE` statement to do this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [Favorite Color]='Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'People who like Red'
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN [Favorite Color]='Yellow' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'People who like Yellow'
FROM Table1
```

Comment: Hilarious that we wrote the EXACT same answer.  That's hard to do.

Comment: Even harder when you consider the answer will not work for the OP.  `CASE WHEN` is not supported in the MS Access Jet/ACE db engine.  That detail was easy to miss, especially before Paul Sasik edited the question to include the [ms-access] tag.

Answer (score 3):

```
select sum(case when [Favorite Color] = 'Red' then 1 else 0 end) as "People Who Like Red",
       sum(case when [Favorite Color] = 'Yellow' then 1 else 0 end) as "People Who Like Yellow"
from Table1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this?

```
SELECT Count(*) AS ["People who like Yellow or Red"], Table1.[Favorite Color]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.[Favorite Color]
HAVING (((Table1.[Favorite Color])=[Enter Color]));
```

It will prompt the user to enter a color, which you specify Red or Yellow, and it will display the query to count whichever color you choose individually?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
select count(*) as "People who like Yellow or Red", Color
form Table1
group by color
```